# Heap differences Node 4 and Node 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

I have an express web app running on 2 ubuntu bare metal servers, balancing the load from nginx on a 3rd server.

On the first machine (app1), I have node v4.4.7. The second one (app2), was recently upgraded to use node v6.3.0. Since the upgrade, app2 throws errors like:

```
FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy
 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

and:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

In both servers I use `--max-old-space-size=2048`.
Both machines have a huge amount of RAM, and both use less than half of it.

The question is, what has changed from v4 to v6? Is there any new node option to increase heap size?

Comment: When a process goes out of memory like that, the answer is rarely to increase the memory, and often to look at the code and find out why it use that much memory.

Comment: I agree. But why does it use that much memory only on v6?

Comment: That I can t tell without a single line of code, but a good start would be any function that changed between v4 and v6, and a good node.js debugger.

Comment: I mean, the code I execute is exactly the same on both machines. If there is some kind of memory leak, it should also affect to the process running on version 4. But with v4 runs fine. Only v6 hits the limit.

Comment: Unless some function comportment changed between v4 and v6, which would have a impact if the reccommended use is different, or if you are using now deprecated functions. That is why upgrading between major version is a pain in all languages, and why legacy code exist.

Comment: I have unfortunately the same problem (and no solution) - after an upgrade from v4 to v6, our servers started to experience memory issues every few days. The heap usage increases until it reaches a peak and drops - sometimes around 500 MB (good) but sometimes it goes over 1 GB (and the event loop lag gets terrible) before it drops.

Comment: @JakubHolý if it helps you, I found out that the problem was rendering a React component on the backend, which was attaching event listeners. The problem was solved by running those addListener() functions only on the browser, but I didn't make any research on how that function is treated differently on node 4 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct option is `--max_old_space_size`.  Note the underscore instead of the dash.  If running Node 6, execute `node --v8-options` to get a list of all node V8 options.

Comment: Was answering specifically _Is there any new node option to increase heap size?_